# Scope not updating after $http AJAX call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, scope

The following code is in my controller - when I reach the console.log() line, nothing is printed out.  The AJAX call returns a valid array.  I tried using $scope.$apply but I got an process already in progress error, I'm assuming because using $http automatically starts the digest cycle:

```
var mmyApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('TasksController',  TasksController);
 function TasksController($scope, $http) {
$scope.transactions = [];
$http.get('transactions').then(function (response) {
             $scope.transactions = response.data;     
     }, function (error) {
         throw error;
     });
console.log($scope.transactions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$http.get` is asynchronous. When you call your `console.log`, your GET request didn't return yet. You can move it inside the handle body to see that it works:

```
$http.get('transactions').then(function (response) {
             $scope.transactions = response.data;     
             console.log($scope.transactions);
     }, function (error) {
         throw error;
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that AJAX calls made with [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in AngularJS are asynchronous, that is, they do not run in sequence with the rest of the code, unless you set it that way.

Therefore when the `console.log` is executed, the request still has not finished processing. The correct thing is that you run `console.log` after performing the assignment of the variable in the AJAX call, in this way:

```
var mmyApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('TasksController',  TasksController);
function TasksController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.transactions = [];

    $http.get('transactions').then(function (response) {
        $scope.transactions = response.data;
        console.log($scope.transactions);     
    }, function (error) {
        throw error;
 });
}
```